# Shortest path between cities that you can use either train or bus DYNAMIC PROGRAMMING

Tags: algorithm, graph, dynamic-programming, shortest-path, memoization

there is a problem which drives me crazy!

--This should be solved by dynamic programming btw--

I have 80 cities, and there is an additional starting city to travel from. I'm required to find the shortest path to each of these 80 cities from a single city. But the problem is the traveler could use either bus or train.

In the input, the information about if there is a train way between two specific cities, if there is a busway between to specific cities, the average traveling time for a traveler who uses one of these options, and the average traveling time between the bus station and train station in a city if it has both will be provided. During the travel to a specific city, we can change our transportation option at most once.

I think that I may abstract this problem into a level that each city is a vertex and since this structure may not be an acyclic graph; I may use an algorithm like Bellman-Ford or another algorithm that runs in O(V.E) time. But there may be 2 edges between two cities, one for the bus and one for the train. Then I have no idea about how could I handle this. So the recursion would depend on 2 parameters, the designated vertex and the maximum number of edges to reach that city. But here I guess I have another parameter about this train-bus issue which I have no idea how to handle, bc as I stated we may change our transportation at most once during the travel.

My concern is simply if there are two cities that we can change our transportation option throughout the journey, changing the transportation option in the first possible city due to the lower cost may not cause the lowest total cost, because maybe changing the transportation option in the second possible city lowers the cost more than the first city lowered.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: And it should be solved by Dynamic programming

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you only have the bus option, in order to solve this you can use [`Dijkstra's algorithm`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), which is usually used to find a path from single node to another but can be easily modified to find the shortest path to all of the nodes in the graph. We will indeed take each city to be node and each lane to be an edge and we are done :)

Now for the interesting part, when you can switch between train and bus only once. Let's create two graphs, `G_b` and `G_t`, where `G_t` contains only the trains paths and `G_b` contains only the buses paths, the weights are the travel times. The next step is to connect with one directed edge all the nodes from `G_b` to the corresponding node in `G_t`. Create another Copy of this graph but this time connect `G_t` to `G_b`.

Now run the `Dijkstra's algorithm` on these two graphs. When you want to know which time was the shortest to a specific city - take the minimum from all 4 occurences of this city.
You can know if we have changed transportation by checking if we changed layer in the graph.

The time complexity is lower than Bellman-Ford by far since we only ran Dijkstra's algorithm twice. `O(E + V log V)`

Comment: Oh sorry! I forgot to put the most important information since I get used to the problem so much. I'm required to use Dynamic Programming :( But in either case, I think I can construct 2 graphs as you suggested and create some copies to connect. And at the end take the minimum of 4 cities which are the same city indeed.

Comment: But I need concrete thought about this if I use dynamic programming; then I will have a matrix which has the vertices in columns but number of maximum edges to go to that vertex from source node. Then should I create a matrix for G-T and G-B then connect and copy that and connect from the other side? Sorry again for mislead :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making each city a node, you can opt to make each bus stop as well as each train stop a node, and have edges between adjacent bus stops and adjacent train stops, as well as between the bus stops and train stops in the same cities. Then you can run some SSSP algorithm, maybe Dijkstra's, which runs much faster than Bellman-Ford, and works for acyclic graphs (provided there are no negative edges) from the source city.

To ensure you don't change method of transportation more than once, you can add an extra boolean parameter to each state, which marks whether you've changed transportation method at some point previously.

Comment: Oh that's an interesting solution which never came to my mind! I forgot to say that this problem should be solved by dynamic programming but I think I can use this method to create nodes for stations and use a Dynamic programming algorithm at the same time.  But my question here is that, for example I come to a state where I have already changed my transportation option, but changing here at that state may be more optimal than changing it before. How could I store all of these in matrix/matrices? Thanks for your immediate response :)

Comment: In such a case there would be another path that doesn't include changing stations that leads to this part. So you would have a visited array of the form vis[N][2][2], where N is the number of cities, and the 2nd dimension stores if you took a bus or train here, and the 3rd stores if you've swapped transportation before. So to answer your question, even though the current "shortest path" involves having changed transportation already (stored in `vis[i][j][1]`, you'll have another "shortest path" that didn't already change transportation stored in `vis[i][j][0]` that you can go off of.

Comment: Oh since I stored both of them, at the end I could take the minimum when I arrived at my designated city, right?  Thank you for your response and further clarification, this is so much appreciated! :)

Comment: In usual Bellman-Ford algorithm, the problem is defined upon two parameters which are the designated node to reach and the maximum number of edges to reach that node like explained here: https://downey.io/notes/omscs/cs6515/dynamic-programming-shortests-paths/ Since the graph would not be acyclic, should be the array a 4-dim array that I also stored that information i=the max number of edges to reach that node, like I have already share? This is so much complicated for me, sorry for bothering you again and again :(